# Strange: AngularJS $scope can show everything in View except Firebase user.email

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Something strange happening here or am I missing something else? I have the following template view:

**user-profile.html**

```
<div id="divUserProfile" ng-controller="userProfileController">
    <h1>User Profile</h1>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Organizational Information</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <label id="lblEmail" class="label-value">{{email}}</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Contact Number</label>
                    <input id="txtContactNo" type="text" value="{{contactNumber}}">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"])
.config( // $routeProvider config here... )
.controller("userProfileController", function ($scope) {
    console.log("This is userProfileController!");

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log("User = " + user.email); // User does exist and singed in!
            $scope.email = user.email; // Email not rendered!
            console.log("$scope.email = " + $scope.email); // It does contain my email address!
        } else {
            console.log("User = " + user);
        }
    });
});
```

**Problem: `{{email}}` not rendered!** But if you hardcoded `$scope.email = "ee@eee.com";`, it shows up! Also, if you `console.log($scope.email)`, it does contain my signed in email address but never rendered, why??? In fact, I have populated more labels on my `<fieldset>` and all rendered properly with the same `$scope` except the one assigned with Firebase's `user.email`, why? I tried to replace `onAuthStateChanged` with `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;`, not working either.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with it? Let me know if you need me to show more other parts of the code, thanks!

**NOTE:** I also notice that Google Chrome's autofill has taken my `txtContactNo` as my login input box, not sure if this has any connection with the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $apply:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"])
.config( // $routeProvider config here... )
.controller("userProfileController", function ($scope) {

    console.log("This is userProfileController!");

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log("User = " + user.email); // User does exist and singed in!
            $scope.email = user.email; // Email not rendered!
            //IMPORTANT
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log("$scope.email = " + $scope.email); // It does contain my email address!
        } else {
            console.log("User = " + user);
        }
    });
});
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

You can also use `$apply()` to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript. Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) $apply has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to $apply is **needed only** when implementing custom event callbacks, or **when working with third-party library callbacks**.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your detailed explanation, really appreciate that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you modify something outside of angular code -- you should call $scope.$apply() or $rootScope.$apply() to let angular to detect changes.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer given by **@georgeawg** was cool enough, I later found another alternative for, perhaps, **a better Angular-Firebase integration approach** without using `$scope.$apply()`, i.e. **[AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire)**. It may seem more codes required, but **it could offer more other reliabilities and conveniences** pertaining to Firebase activities in AngularJS. Here is the simplified example on how to implement it:

**index.html**

```
<!-- Your Firebase and AngularJS references go here -->

<!-- AngularFire -->
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

**index.js or app.js**

```
/* Inject firebase to your Angular module */
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "firebase"])
.config( // $routeProvider config here... )
/* Add $firebaseAuth to your controller */
.controller("userProfileController", [ "$scope", "$firebaseAuth", function ($scope) {

    /* Be sure to put '$' before onAuthStateChanged() also */
    $firebaseAuth().$onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            /* {{email}} is now rendered without using $scope.$apply()! */
            $scope.email = user.email; 
        } else {
            // Do something else here.
        }
    });
}]);
```

**Conclusion:**

Which means the explanation of **@georgeawg** is still valid: If it's **outside the Angular Execution Context**, you need to use `$scope.$apply()` **unless** the services have been **injected** inside the Angular Execution Context.

Hope this helps!